# Run garbage collection in debugged application from within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, garbage-collection

Is there an easy way to trigger garbage collection (as if running `System.gc()`) from within eclipse on an application running in debug mode?

Background:
By coincidence I found out that an object still existed which I thought had long been garbage collected, since it was only held by a weak reference (or so I thought). I suspected that I had a hard reference flying around somewhere and therefore a memory leak, but it turned out the garbage collector simply didn't run (maybe there wasn't enough memory pressure). This is usually fine, but it's not when I am trying to identify memory leaks. Therefore I need a way to trigger garbage collection manually.

Comment: Relying on one object getting garbage collected is not a good way, because it is nearly impossible to know what exactly the garbage collector does or when. Even running System.gc() does not make sure that all objects are collected which can be collected. Instead, you should get your VM into a state where you know the available memory is low, but should not be, and then taking a snapshot and examining what kind of objects are there which should not be there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I am aware of that. However, when I trigger garbage collection and the object is finalized, I KNOW that I can't have a memory leak - I will then only have to analyze the objects that did not get gc'd. Being able to trigger GC is therefore a huge simplification.

Comment: I fully agree to that. Some profilers (not debuggers) allow you to take memory snapshots and then statically analyse the memory, including simulating a full garbage collection (hence ignoring the objects which could be garbage collected, even if they haven't been.). I think that's what you actually need.

Comment: This would be the best option if I was to analyze a full-fledged application. But at the moment I am implementing an object lifecycle and just want to sneak peek whether it could work as I expect it to do. And with eclipse finding all instances of a class is done in milliseconds without even having to pause a single thread - in combination with a forced GC this is substantially faster than taking a whole heap dump.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried visual vm? it is an easy to use tool to monitor any running application, in which you can also force a garbage collection. It might also help you identify your memory leak using a heap dump.

Comment: I have worked with visual vm before, but to be honest, I haven't found an option to run a GC cycle, can you point me to where I find it?

Comment: Old track but this option is available in the monitor tab for the visualvm application for JDK 1.8 (bin folder). The same options if also available via JConsole.